# What's wrong with this iframe?

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm using this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
        height="100%" width="100%"
        src="http://www.google.com/search?q=<?php echo $plus ?>">
    </a>
</iframe>
```

No matter how much I increase the height percentage, it remains the same. The height doesn't change at all... Any ideas why?

[This](http://www.jsfiddle.net/fhfg2/) is related.

Comment: It exists. The purpose of iframes is not to try to conceal the URL of a document.

Comment: For one thing, the marginheight, marginwidth, height and width attributes. Consider CSS.

Comment: It changes for me. Please see: http://www.jsfiddle.net/fhfg2/3/

Comment: What's the `<\a>` doing in the IFRAME?

Comment: No it doesn't whatever value i change..Te height is the same :(

Comment: For me, the height is huge. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox...Its just with fireofx and not with other browsers :(

Answer (score 1):

It will only span the height of the parent element.

So if this iFrame is in your html/body element without height definition it will default to the browser height.

http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html

If you don't want to use CSS you will need to define the height of the body tag and all child elements thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the `</a>` from the tags?

Also, 100% is going to fill the container element.  Make sure you have `position:relative;` in your element's styles and you have their heights/widths setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parent height. If your parent has no set height, what does `100%` of that height mean? Try this:

```
html, body, #your_parent
{
  height: 100%; /* Or some other value. You get the idea, right? */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Change those percents to whatever you like, just have *some* height and width to reference to. Also, remove that `</a`> closing tag. It shouldn't belong there.

Good luck!

Comment: For some reason when i change the doctype it works..But now i forgot what doctype it was.And when i validate still the same problem comes :(