# Problem with Doctype and iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%" src="http://www.google.com/search?q=<?php echo $plus ?>"></a></iframe>
```

The width changes according to what value i set but the height remains the same no matter what % i give.

The doctype which i had originally used,worked but when i validated it it didn't work.

The problem is not with CSS as the common CSS was used in the original and the current one.

NOTE: I don't know what doctype i used earlier..So i have no clue about it :(

Please help..Thanks

Comment: @541 , doctype should come in the start of the page , otherwise its invalid

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to set iframe height in percentage is using client side script - let me know if you need help implementing this.

Comment: -1 for posting duplicate

Comment: I cant understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Yes mate i need a little help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats wrong with this iframe ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417481/whats-wrong-with-this-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
       var frame_height_percentage = 50;
       var oFrame = $("#MyFrame");
       oFrame.height(oFrame.parent().height() * (frame_height_percentage / 100));
});
```

This will set the frame  height to be 50% its parent height.